# usercontrol с различными шаблонами данных

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

добрый день. Есть некоторый объект, приходящий от сервера вк. Данные постоянно разные, могут включать массивы объектов и кучу других массивов. От сюда вопрос: как можно программно управлять привязкой (не создавая ее в коде) создать представление для такого объекта. Объект представляет собой запись на стене вк. Есть такая идея: разбить все на маленькие дататемлейты (отдельно аудио, фото, видео, опросы и т.д), и при наполнении данными моего юзер контролла каким-то образом программно определять, если тип данных есть, то загружаем в контролл какой-то вид темплейта (их загружаться будет несколько)

Answer (score 1):

Почитал ваши вопросы и то ли не понял, что вы хотите, то ли вы как-то не так представляете себе задачу.
На мой взгляд для стены вк идеально подойдет обычный `ListView` с `TemplateSelector`-ом для отображения разных шаблонов для элементов стены. Если объект содержит, например, список треков, то в качестве шаблона для этого элемента берете опять же `ListView` и так далее. Байндите его к массиву объектов стены и всё. За загрузку/незагругку лишнего будет отвечать виртуализация. Прикрутите это все к `IncrementalLoadingCollection` и вообще ресурсы жрать не будет.

Comment: и что же я в этом темплейт селекторе выбирать будут ? 11! различных комбинаций с шаблонами ? ладно, если было бы всего 5 - 10 шаблонов, можно было бы переключать, но писать конструкции для переключения сотен комбинаций из этих шаблонов - как-то не айс. 
да и я уже реализовал все через юзерконтролл, который при биндинге подгружает элементы сам

Comment: Какие сотни комбинаций? Это список. Каждый элемент списка - отдельный шаблон, в зависимости от типа элемента. На стене что, сотни разных типов объектов? Их сотни в общей сумме, но самих шаблонов всего - аудио, картинка, пост итп. Вы, видимо, не понимаете, что  хотите, либо совсем не разбираетесь в теме.

Comment: всего типов объектов 11, а их комбинаций - факториал 11, ибо в одном элементе списка может встречаться различное их кол-во, в т.ч. и вложенные такие же списки, и, теоретически, их может быть бесконечное множество

Comment: Какая разница сколько комбинаций, если темплейт селектор будет сам выбирать из 11 шаблонов?

Comment: так эти шаблоны в один элемент списка необходимо будет поместить, а темплейтселектор их просто переключает для каждого нового элемента

Comment: Для списка в элементе списка этот же темплейтселектор. Там больше одного уровня вложенности не бывает.

Comment: но как выбрать несколько шаблонов ? когда аудио и фото, например, либо аудио, фото, видео и тд ?

Comment: Каждый элемент списка1-стена является списком2-пост из элементов аудио, фото, видео.

Comment: ну вот я и спрашиваю о том, как в один элемент списка загнать несколько других элементов списка, учитывая то, что элементы каждый раз разные. 
я это все реализовал через юзер контролл, интересно было бы посмотреть на ваш способ